# What is mean by <beans:beans> and <beans>

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

What is the differences between

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

and

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Could you please explain what is the difference between these two.

Answer (score 1):

It's an XML namespace used to separate potentially conflicting element names, so there's no real difference.

[XML Namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent.
You can say the full name of the element is  ns : elementName
e.g.:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans : beans
```

if you say **xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"**  than it means "if you see an element without a namespace prefix, assume a default namespace of "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

if you say **xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"**  than it means "if you see an element with a beans: prefix, assume it's shorthand for "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

Answer (score 1):

The key to understand this is the `xmlns` value. In both of the cases it's:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

This specifies the **default** schema for the document. This means that every tag in the XML will should be part of this schema, **unless** explicitly specify which other schema is it part of.

Specifying that a tag comes from another schema is usually done by `<schemaName:tagName>` pattern. So, for example, if the tag `name` is part of the schema `foo`, you have to use it with `<foo:name>`.

When picking a default schema for the document, you're allowed to **skip** the schema name, like in your example with `<beans>`. In this case, the `<beans>` tag must be specified in the schema, pointed with `xmlns`.

In the other case, you're explicitly specifying that the tag `beans` is part of the schema with alias `beans`, which result to `<beans:beans>`. However, if you don't have a `xmlns:beans=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` definition, you'd result with an invalid XML.

Personally, I'd prefer always explicitly provide the schema alias, though.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct and the second one isn't. The difference comes from your "default namespace". Your default namespace is `beans`. If your default namespace would be something else, like `context` for example, then you would need to explicitly define a `beans` namespace (which you haven't done in your example) and use the `beans:beans` style.

There is a different use case for nested `<beans>` element where you use a new `<beans>` tag inside your root `<beans>` tag:

> for the purpose of defining a subset of beans with certain default values or to be registered only when certain profile(s) are active. Any such nested  element must be declared as the last element in the document.

but your examples aren't related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, it allows you NOT to add the namespace in front of the element you choose that belongs the default namespace.
xmlns="namespace"  
From the above example if:
i)xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

Then you can use element <beans> as well as <beans:beans> - explicit syntax.

ii) xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

Then you can use <p> as well as <xmlns:p> - explicit syntax.

NOTE: You can only set the default namespace once using xmlns!